# Match any url in Mongoose with or without http(s) or www

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, mongodb, mongoose

What I'm trying to achieve is to find a way to verify if a URL already exists in a MongoDB document, without saving the URL twice, one with HTTP(s)(www) protocol, and other clean of HTTP(s)(www) to perform the match.
For example, if the MongoDB document contains a record:

```
'url': "http://mysite.co?search=pattern&co=43"
```

So, I want to perform a search:

```
MyCollection.find({'url': "mysite.co?search=pattern&co=43"})...
MyCollection.find({'url': "http://mysite.co?search=pattern&co=43"})...
MyCollection.find({'url': "https://mysite.co?search=pattern&co=43"})...
MyCollection.find({'url': "http://www.mysite.co?search=pattern&co=43"})...
MyCollection.find({'url': "https://www.mysite.co?search=pattern&co=43"})...
```

The search should match with the URL actually saved in the document.

I'm trying to use the following regex:

```
MyCollection.find({'url': new RegExp('^https?:\/\/(www.)?(' + 'mysite.co?search=pattern&co=43' + ')+$', 'gim')})...
```

However, I'm not very clever creating regex expressions, and I still struggle with it. Seems that the question mark in the URL breaks the regex, and I'm not pretty sure if just using a replace from '?' to '\?' is the right way to go.

The search must match 'exactly' the URL in the DB, except for the HTTP(s)(www) protocol. I mean, if the URL in the document contains other params:

```
'url': "http://mysite.co?search=pattern&co=43&other=more_params"
```

The search should not be matched this time.

I'm using Mongoose and nodejs.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

Based on your answers, I have improved a little bit the regex and scaping for the URL:

First, a function to trim and 'clean' the URL of HTTP(s) or (www):

```
String.prototype.url_clean = function() {
    return this.trim().replace(/^(http(s|):\/\/)?(www\.|)/g, '');
};
```

And a function to escape the URL:

```
RegExp.escape = function(s) {
    return s.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+!<=:?.\/\\^$|#\s,]/g, '\\$&');
};
```

So I can perform the search:

```
MyCollection.find({'url': new RegExp('^(http(s|):\/\/)?(www\.|)(' + RegExp.escape(url.url_clean()) + ')(|\s)+$', "gim")})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the problem is you must escape specific elements of a url from the regex (such as '?') `/^http(s|):\/\/(www\.|)mysite\.co\?search=pattern&co=43/`

Instead i would write a script that pulled all the records, split them into individual fields, save the new document. Query on those new fields instead of using regex

Comment: Would `http(s)` and `www` be optional if this regex was used? What part indicates that? Thank you!

Comment: Yes. Using a regex groups ‘()’ and making elements in the group optional by using the “or” switch ‘|’

Answer (score 3):

It looks fine you just forgot to escape some characters:

```
db.getCollection('regex').find({
    "url": new RegExp('^https?:\/\/(www.)?(' + 'mysite\.co\\?search=pattern&co=43' + ')+$', 'gim')
})
```

More on regex in MongoDB you can read [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#syntax-restrictions)

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer help me to make sure that I was in the right way. However, @d3l33t answered first.